# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.support.IsNewStrategyFactory

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-commons

after upgrading spring boot version to 2.6.6 and spring data commons version to 2.6.4.
seeing this error.

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.support.IsNewStrategyFactory
at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2309) ~[?:?]